# Embedded Linux: Adding device file to existing device sysfs class

Tags: embedded-linux, sysfs

I am using Linux kernel release 5.4. I have one kernel built-in driver, which creates a sysfs class: `/sys/night_owl/tick1/*` using `class_create()` and `device_create_file()` function. I am developing another kernel loadable module, which reuses the `/sys/class/night_owl` class, this means I will have something like this `/sys/class/night_owl/tick2/*`. Does Linux kernel support this feature or are there any keywords for me to search on this?

Comment: There are **driver** and **device** attributes. You should understand first what you want to have and what the difference between them.